# Protractor: Facing issues to upload files/images in safari browser with send keys

Tags: file-upload, safari, protractor

We are using Protractor for Automating our Angular application. We are using below element to upload images to application with *element.sendKeys('imagepath')* which is working fine for chrome and Firefox(with some extra capabilities). But this is not working for safari browser... Any ideas here...

> 

Comment: Do you have any errors? WHat is not working?

Comment: It says element is not visible, cannot perform actions on it.